# How do i use '%' symbol in FXML statements

Tags: java, javafx, escaping, fxml

When I write fxml markup, I get a warning from my IDE when i use the '%' symbol within strings, such as:

```xml
<Label text="% Tax:" />
```

I also receive a RuntimeException when running my JavaFX application and building the UI.

So my question is: How do i use the '%' symbol correctly?

Comment: What compile errors? The code you posted doesn't give me any errors at all. (Do you really mean `System.out.println(...)`?) Also, see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for formatting code.

Comment: If you actually meant `printf`, you escape it with `%%`.

Comment: <Label text="% Tax: "
        GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>

Comment: i get a compile error with the '%' in and it works fine without.

Comment: %% is what i was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the comments, I just tested this in an old project, and you do seem to be somewhat correct. However, it is not a compile error! For instance, if I write something like this in fxml:

```xml
<Label text="% Output:" />
```

I get an InvocationTargetException when building the UI. All you need to do is to escape the symbol like this:

```xml
<Label text="\% Output:" />
```

The reason you think this is a compile error is likely because your IDE is marking it as incorrect. This is just your IDE being clever.

And by the way, your question could have been a lot clearer.

Comment: Just out of interest why are you commenting on my style of question when you've never asked a question yourself...?

Comment: @spotpush Neither me nor any of the commenters uderstood your question at first hand, so it was not clear what your problem was. Someone even mentioned that they did not believe you (but that comment seems to be gone now). I was not trying to be rude, just suggesting your questions to be more clearly written :)